# Solidity: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider') in a simple HelloWorld contract by trying to test

Tags: testing, typeerror, solidity

I'm trying to test a simple HelloWorld.sol File:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract HelloWorld 
{
    function hello() public pure returns (string memory)
    {
        return "Hello, World";
    }
}
```

with a HelloWorld.ts testfile

```
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers" ;
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { expect } from "chai";


describe("hello world", function()
{
    it("should say hello world", async function () 
    {
        const HelloWorld = await ethers.getContractFactory("HelloWorld");
        const hello = await HelloWorld.deploy();

        expect(hello).to.equal("Hello, World");
       
    });
});
```

After calling: npx hardhat test

```
I got result with a error message:

hello world
    1) should say hello world


  0 passing (78ms)
  1 failing

  1) hello world
       should say hello world:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:4:61)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
      at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
      at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1608:43)
      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\provider-proxy.ts:7:1)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
```

I already did an internet research for answers/ fixing, but was not able to find an appropriate one..

So I don't know how to solve it and what am I supposed to do?

Thanks in advance!

please see above

Don't know why i get this error...

Comment: You didn't configure you're rpc provider properly, you need to setup hardhat with an infura node and a default user mneumonic or private key etc

Comment: Because I'm a newby on that here is what I installed, sidenote it's from an online course - https://theprimeagen.github.io/web3-smart-contracts/   
--->         
npm install --global yarn,
yarn init -y,
yarn add -D hardhat,
npx hardhat
--->
Typescript:
yarn add -D ts-node typescript
--->  
Testing types:
yarn add -D chai @types/node @types/mocha @types/chai
-->
npx hardhat compile -> works fine...,
npx hardhat test -> described error...
--->
Is the anything more I have to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at your contract instance, once you deploy the contract with

```
const hello = await HelloWorld.deploy();
```

You must call the `hello()` function to get the correct output.
Update your code with

```
describe("hello world", function()
{
    it("should say hello world", async function () 
    {
        const HelloWorld = await ethers.getContractFactory("HelloWorld");
        const helloWorldContract = await HelloWorld.deploy();
        await helloWorldContract.deployed();

        const hello = await helloWorldContract.hello();
        expect(hello).to.be.equal("Hello, World");
       
    });
});
```

You will notice that I also added the code `await helloWorldContract.deployed();` this will wait until the deployment transaction is already on chain.

Good luck !

Comment: Thx a lot it's working now, obviously it was a problem with yarn. 
A new installation completely with npm fixed the problems..

Answer (score 5):

For me, changing the version of ethers to `^5.7.2` in *package.json*, (I had `6.2.0` installed) then deleting the node_modules folder and running `yarn` to install the packages again cleared the error.

[referenced from here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/144604)

Answer (score 1):

what @sung said is correct. but better still, rather than manually downgrading your ethers version in your `.json`  file, and then installing your node modules and trying to remember all the packages that you might have installed previously. Simply run `npm install ethers@^5.7.2`. After running the command, npm will downgrade the ethers package to version `5.7.2` while keeping your other packages intact. The `^` symbol in front of the version number is used to specify a range of compatible versions. In this case, it means that npm will install the latest version of the `5.x.x` range that is compatible with version `5.7.2`. Since `5.7.2` is the specific version you want, npm will install that version as it is within the specified range.

-Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

My way around this was degrading my ethers version to 5.7.2 ie

```
npm i ethers@5.7.2
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message is indicating that the JsonRpcProvider object is undefined. This error is likely being caused by an issue with the @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers library.

A possible solution is to update the @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers package to the latest version, as the issue may have been fixed in a newer version. You can do this by running the following command in your terminal:

```
npm install @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@latest
```

If updating the library doesn't resolve the issue, you could also try checking the documentation and example code provided by the library's creators, or reaching out to the library's support channels to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. there are have 2 options

option 1. Downgrade ethers to 5.7.2  using

```
npm install ethers@5.7.2
const provider = new thers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545" );
```

option 2. Have latest version and in use

```
const { ethers, JsonRpcProvider } = require("ethers");
const provider = new JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545")
```